# How would one implement the AutoContrast, Posterize, and Solarize augmentations from RandAugment in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-augmentation

I am busy implementing RandAugment in Tensorflow and have successfully created functions for most of the augmentations as shown in the code below.

```
def brightness(image, M):
    M = tf.math.minimum(M, 0.95)
    M = tf.math.maximum(M, 0.05)
    B = M - 1
    image = tf.image.adjust_brightness(image, delta=B)
    image = tf.clip_by_value(image, clip_value_min=0, clip_value_max=1)

    return image

def colour(image, M):
    M = tf.math.minimum(M, 0.95)
    M = tf.math.maximum(M, 0.05)
    image = tf.image.adjust_saturation(image, M)
    return image

def contrast(image, M):
    M = tf.math.minimum(M, 0.95)
    M = tf.math.maximum(M, 0.05)
    image = tf.image.adjust_contrast(image, contrast_factor=M)
    return image

def equalise(image, M):
    image = tf.cast(image*255, dtype='uint8')
    image = tfa.image.equalize(image, bins=256)
    image = tf.cast(image/255, dtype='float64')
    return image

def rotate(image, M):
    theta = -np.pi/6 + 2*M*np.pi/6
    image = tfa.image.rotate(image, angles=theta, interpolation='bilinear')
    return image

def sharpness(image, M):
    image = tfa.image.sharpness(image, factor=M)
    return image

def shear_x(image, M):
    R = -0.3 + 2*M*0.3
    image = tfa.image.shear_x(image, level=R, replace=0)
    return image

def shear_y(image, M):
    R = -0.3 + 2*M*0.3
    image = tfa.image.shear_y(image, level=R, replace=0)
    return image

def translate_x(image, M):
    dx = -10 + 2*M*10
    image = tfa.image.translate(image, translations=[dx, 0], interpolation='bilinear', fill_mode='constant', fill_value=0)
    return image

def translate_y(image, M):
    dy = -10 + 2*M*10
    image = tfa.image.translate(image, translations=[0, dy], interpolation='bilinear', fill_mode='constant', fill_value=0)
    return image
```

I have been unable to figure out how to implement AutoContrast, Posterize, and Solarize. The descriptions for these augmentations are as follows:

- AutoContrast: Maximizes the image contrast by setting the darkest (lightest) pixel to black (white).
- Posterize: Reduces each pixel to *B* bits.
- Solarize: Inverts all pixels above a threshold value of *T* [0, 1].

Does anyone know of a straightforward way these can be implemented using Tensorflow functions, in a similar manner to the other functions I have implemented?

Comment: The code for randaugment is open, see here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/1ebfc4b5fa6b5fad0bd7d422832ae8826e8059f2/models/official/efficientnet/autoaugment.py#L287

Comment: Thanks so much! Been looking for something like this, don't know how I missed it.